# Calculate $(\text{Area}$ $ABCD) \times (\text{Area}$ $XYZW)$

Tags: geometry, area, solution-verification

Consider a $ABCD$ center square $ O $. Let $E,F,G$ and $H$ points inside the sides $AB,BC,CD$ and $DA$, respectively, such that $AE = BF =CG = DH$. It is known that $OA$ intersects $HE$ at point $X,OB$ intersects $EF$ at point $Y, OC$ intersects $FG$ at point $Z$ and $OD$ intersects $GH$ at point $W$. Since Area $EFGH = 1$, calculate $(\text{Area}$ $ABCD) \times (\text{Area}$ $XYZW)$

**Attemp:** WLOG, let $E, F, G, H$ be midpoints. From symmetry, $X, Y, W, Z$, will be nice midpoints too. Since each side of $EFGH=1$, we have that $BE=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ (and similar sides). This means that each side of $ABCD=\frac{2}{\sqrt2}$. The area of $ABCD=2$. Since $X, Y, W, Z$ are the midpoints of $EFGH$, $EX=1/2$. This means that $XY=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$ (and other similar sides). The area of $XYWZ=\frac{1}{2}$. The answer is $1$.

Correct? Can you generalize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the points close to corner $B$ and side $AB$. (Other cyclic cases are similar) From all the rotational symmetries,

$$\begin{align*}
AB &\parallel XY\\
\angle YEB &= \angle XYE &&\text{(alternate angles)}\\
\angle AEX &= \angle EXY &&\text{(alternate angles)}\\
\angle BFY &= \angle AEX &&\text{(symmetry)}\\
\triangle BFE &\sim \triangle EXY&&\text{(AAA)}
\end{align*}$$

Then consider the ratio of sides of squares $ABCD$, $EFGH$ and $XYZW$,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{AB}{EF} &= \frac{AE+EB}{EF}\\
&= \frac{BF + EB}{EF} &&\text{(}AE=BF\text{ given)}\\
&= \frac{BF}{EF} + \frac{EB}{EF}\\
&= \frac{EX}{YX} + \frac{YE}{YX} &&\text{(corresponding sides)}\\
&= \frac{FY}{YX} + \frac{YE}{YX} &&\text{(}EX=FY\text{ symmetry)}\\
&= \frac {EF}{XY}\\
\end{align*}$$

So the side lengths of the three squares are in geometric sequence, so their areas also are in geometric sequence.

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac {(AB)^2}{(EF)^2} &= \frac {(EF)^2}{(XY)^2}\\
(AB)^2(XY)^2 &= (EF)^4\\
&= 1
\end{align*}$$